# Resultados duplicados en VIEW de SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Se que mi duda es básica, pero llevo mucho rato calentándome la cabeza y todavía no llego a una solución.

Esta son mis tablas

```
create table comuna 
(
    id_comuna int primary key not null,
    comuna varchar (20) not null
)

create table tienda
(
    cod_tienda int primary key not null,
    gerente_encargado varchar (30) not null,
    fecha_inauguracion date not null,
    id_comuna int foreign key references comuna (id_comuna) not null
)
```

Los datos ingresados en la tabla

```
insert into comuna (id_comuna,comuna) values (1,'Santiago'),(2,'Rancagua'),(3,'Talca'),(4,'Chillan'),(5,'Antofagasta')
insert into tienda (cod_tienda,gerente_encargado,fecha_inauguracion,id_comuna) values 
(81,'Luis Gonzalez Soto','1990-02-01',2),
(82,'Pedro Leiva Toro','2007-08-17',1),
(83,'Laura Becerra Madrid','1997-11-24',4),
(84,'Gustavo Azocar Reyes','1985-02-21',2),
(85,'Ximena Olguin Baeza','1980-05-19',4),
(86,'Jose Neira Maldonado','2005-07-07',3),
(87,'Gabriela Nielse Soto','2000-12-06',1),
(88,'Manuel Figueroa Molina','2010-06-13',5)
```

Y esta es la vista que quiero crear

```
create view customA as
select
    tienda.cod_tienda,
    tienda.gerente_encargado,
    tienda.id_comuna,
    comuna.comuna
from
    tienda,
    comuna
```

Pero el resultado de las vistas, me arroja las comunas duplicadas:

[image: Resultado de sentencia Select * from customA]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes de especificar cual es la relación que une a las tablas. En este caso, como la colulmna de tiendas, dice que es no nula y hace referencia a comuna id_comuna, puedes utilizar INNER JOIN

```
create view customA as
select
    tienda.cod_tienda,
    tienda.gerente_encargado,
    tienda.id_comuna,
    comuna.comuna
from
    tienda inner join comuna on tienda.id_comuna = comuna.id_comuna
```

[image: Resultados]